# Error when compiling c++ file: Undefined symbols

Tags: c++, linker, g++

I'm trying to compile someone else's C++ code. I have 0 experience with C++ myself. I'm using g++ on a MAC to compile one of the .cpp files that I received. When I do `g++ main.cpp` I get an Undefined symbols error. When googling the answers seem to be about a wrong link between files, but I don't know how to link files. 
How can I get the file to compile? I pasted the full code below.

```
Undefined symbols:
  "initializeFitness()", referenced from:
      runEvolution()     in ccZXBTDH.o
  "Grid::GetNeighbourhood(int, int, std::vector<Agent**, std::allocator<Agent**> >&)", referenced from:
      runEvolution()     in ccZXBTDH.o
      runEvolution()     in ccZXBTDH.o
      runEvolution()     in ccZXBTDH.o
  "Grid::Grid()", referenced from:
      runEvolution()     in ccZXBTDH.o
  "Reaper::GetAgentToKill()", referenced from:
      runEvolution()     in ccZXBTDH.o
  "Cupid::GetRandomBreeder()", referenced from:
      runEvolution()     in ccZXBTDH.o
  "Reaper::Select()", referenced from:
      runEvolution()     in ccZXBTDH.o
  "Grid::~Grid()", referenced from:
      runEvolution()     in ccZXBTDH.o
      runEvolution()     in ccZXBTDH.o
  "Breeder::Breed(Agent**, Agent**)", referenced from:
      runEvolution()     in ccZXBTDH.o
  "Cupid::Select()", referenced from:
      runEvolution()     in ccZXBTDH.o
  "Cupid::GetEmptyCell()", referenced from:
      runEvolution()     in ccZXBTDH.o
  "Agent::GetType()", referenced from:
      runEvolution()     in ccZXBTDH.o
      runEvolution()     in ccZXBTDH.o
      runEvolution()     in ccZXBTDH.o
      runEvolution()     in ccZXBTDH.o
  "Breeder::ProcessNeighbourhood(std::vector<Agent**, std::allocator<Agent**> > const&)", referenced from:
      runEvolution()     in ccZXBTDH.o
  "FateAgent::GetGenome(double*)", referenced from:
      runEvolution()     in ccZXBTDH.o
      runEvolution()     in ccZXBTDH.o
  "Cupid::GetParents()", referenced from:
      runEvolution()     in ccZXBTDH.o
  "Agent::IncreaseAge()", referenced from:
      runEvolution()     in ccZXBTDH.o
  "Grid::GetAgent(int, int)", referenced from:
      runEvolution()     in ccZXBTDH.o
      runEvolution()     in ccZXBTDH.o
      runEvolution()     in ccZXBTDH.o
      runEvolution()     in ccZXBTDH.o
      runEvolution()     in ccZXBTDH.o
      runEvolution()     in ccZXBTDH.o
      runEvolution()     in ccZXBTDH.o
      runEvolution()     in ccZXBTDH.o
      runEvolution()     in ccZXBTDH.o
      runEvolution()     in ccZXBTDH.o
      runEvolution()     in ccZXBTDH.o
      runEvolution()     in ccZXBTDH.o
      runEvolution()     in ccZXBTDH.o
      runEvolution()     in ccZXBTDH.o
      runEvolution()     in ccZXBTDH.o
      runEvolution()     in ccZXBTDH.o
  "FateAgent::GetSelectedCount()", referenced from:
      runEvolution()     in ccZXBTDH.o
      runEvolution()     in ccZXBTDH.o
  "Breeder::GetGenome(double*)", referenced from:
      runEvolution()     in ccZXBTDH.o
  "Agent::GetFitness()", referenced from:
      runEvolution()     in ccZXBTDH.o
      runEvolution()     in ccZXBTDH.o
      runEvolution()     in ccZXBTDH.o
  "Agent::~Agent()", referenced from:
      runEvolution()     in ccZXBTDH.o
  "Grid::DoMovement()", referenced from:
      runEvolution()     in ccZXBTDH.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are trying to compile only a part of the entire program. Try `g++ *.cpp`
If it still doesnt work, It may be because your program needs an external library.

Comment: This seems to work although it gives me a lot of other errors, but it's mostly declaration errors in the code by the looks of it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

g++ cannot find a bunch of symbols, without any further knowledge of your situation - I would guess you're not compiling all of your source code files before linking.

Little more background:

When you call g++ just one source file argument it compiles the file, then tries to link it to a complete executable.

My recommendation is to compile each source file using the -c flag (the -c flag tells the compiler to compile the file down to object code, but not link it into an executable).

```
g++ -c main.cpp
g++ -c file1.cpp
g++ -c file2.cpp
```

The above commands will create object files with the .cpp replaced with .o. You can then link them all together by doing something like

```
g++ main.o file1.o file2.o
```

This will produce an executable a.out which you can run. This should help you with missing symbol linker errors.

If you're going to do anything more complicated than this I would highly suggest investigating in using a Makefile to build the code.

Answer (score 2):

I can only guess here. How many files are in the project? Does it have any libraries?

If you have libraries you need to link them with -l switch

```
g++ -o output_binary_name source_file -lLibrary1 -lLibrary2
```

Or most likely you have more then one source file in the project, you will need to enumerate them

```
g++ -o output_binary_name source_file1 source_file2 source_file2
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that is the code, I think that is debug output.

runEvolution() uses functions that hasn't been defined yet. Look for definitions of those.

Like a lot of people suggested, You may be missing some files, gcc clearly miss something in your code.

Good luck!

Comment: You mixed up everything/ First of all _A is referencd from B_ (in c++) means _B uses A_, not _A uses B_. Then it linker error, not debug.

Comment: @Lol4t0 You are right that it's not the process of debugging. But what I mean is that is the debug output of linker, not as the question mentioned, the code.

Comment: First part of note is more important. Fix it, please.

Answer (score 1):

**assuming the program is not using any library** you should compile all files with `-c` switch and then link them altogether with:

```
g++ -c main.cpp
g++ -c file1.cpp
..
g++ *.o
```

or you can automatically do the same with:

```
g++ *.cpp
```